# Air Android - app.xml manifest additions

Tags: android, xml, air, manifest

How to add these Android settings to an Air for Andoid app.xml manifest?

```
<supports-screens android:
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

This got me a syntax error:

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions>
<![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<supports-screens android:
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
 ]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
  </android>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you have to remove that first 'android:' from your addition.

```
<supports-screens android:
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

should be

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Via this [Adobe post](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/multiple-screen-sizes.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_5) (including for future reference in case that post is removed):

```
<android>
  <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
    <manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal">
      <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
      <compatible-screens>
        <!-- list the screens you support here -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
      </compatible-screens>
    ...
    </manifest>
  ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```